Reinstalling MiKTeX in Windows 11
It shows me the following error when installing MiKTeX, I have used it before, and I don't know why it is giving me errors, I use Windows 11


Change the folder where you are trying to install MiKTeX or delete the aforementioned folder.

OK, try this option. Thanks
